# How to center svg in this react component?

Tags: reactjs, svg

Here is my sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

type AssetProps = {
  className?: string,
  style?: any
};

const SVG_CIRCLE =
  '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10"><path d="M 5 7 C 6.105 7 7 6.105 7 5 C 7 3.895 6.105 3 5 3 C 3.895 3 3 3.895 3 5 C 3 6.105 3.895 7 5 7 Z"></path></svg>';

const createAsset = (gylph: string) => (props: AssetProps) => (
  <div {...props} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: gylph }} />
);

const Circle = createAsset(SVG_CIRCLE);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Here are some circles</h1>
      <h2>
        <Circle />
      </h2>
      <h2>
        <Circle
          style={{
            fill: "blue",
            width: "50px",
            height: "50px",
            border: "1px solid blue"
          }}
        />
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

It is the outcome:

[image]

The SVG graphic is not expanded even though the size is set to 50px each side.

Even if I removed `width="10" height="10"` from `SVG_CIRCLE`, it has no effect. How can I scale the SVG inside this react component?

EDIT:

I have changed the `SVG` line to `const SVG_CIRCLE =
  '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100"><path d="M 5 7 C 6.105 7 7 6.105 7 5 C 7 3.895 6.105 3 5 3 C 3.895 3 3 3.895 3 5 C 3 6.105 3.895 7 5 7 Z"></path></svg>';`

Here is the link to the code example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jz2pp3w33

Comment: add a viewBox attribute set to some suitable value.

Comment: I added `viewPort="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100"` but it has no effect

Comment: I said viewBox, you wrote viewPort.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But if you checked the codesandbox, the corrected code still does not work

Comment: Do you want the SVG to at the center of the div, or just the dot to at the center?

Comment: The SVG is the dot. I want the dot to be at the center and occupy all the available space (as defined by the blue box).

Comment: Why do you write your dot as an `path` instead of `circle`? would be much easier to move it around

Comment: I can change the example to an irregular shape. Don't think it change the core question.

Comment: Change the values in the viewBox, smaller numbers for height and width will make the contents appear larger. Using the same values as the width and height will give you a scale of 1:1, but you want to magnify the contents.